How many maximum nearest-neighbor contacts exist in a self-avoiding walk of length $n$?
Consider the random, self-avoiding walk (SAW) on a 2D lattice as a mechanism for polymer growth. In this random walk, the possible steps the walker can take are along 8 direction, elements of the set $D =\{+x,+y,-x,-y,+x+y, +x-y,-x+y,-x-y\}$. The next step is taken from a random, uniform sampling. Given a starting point $O$, the walker can walk in any of the above directions in discrete steps, but it cannot land on the same spot he had stepped previously. In terms of polymers, each monomer bead is placed on a point the walker has been, and no two beads can occupy the same spot. Here is a depiction of a self-avoiding walk:

The unit cell labelled $O$ is the origin of the walk and $L$ is the current end point in the walk. The transparent beads around $L$ are the only possible points where the next step can be taken. Per the self-avoiding condition, only three such spots can be accessed.
What I am interested in is the number of unique "neighbor contacts" (NC) in a particular random walk of $n$ steps $\gamma(n)$. In a particular SAW of 9 steps $\gamma(9)$, the NC are counted as follows:
For $\gamma(9)$ depicted above, the NC are $8$. The NC are depicted by the golden arrows.
If after $m<n$ steps, if there are no possible extensions to the walk because of the self-avoiding condition, the walk is terminated.
Given a particle $i$, let $M_i$ be the set of all particles in the neighborhood of $i$. Therefore, $j$ is a neighbor of $i$ if $r_i-r_j \in D$, where $r_i$ is the position of particle $i$ on the lattice. In set notation,
$$M_i=\{j | r_i-r_j \in D\}$$
The total number of NC is
$$T = \frac{1}{2}\sum _i |M_i|$$
where $|M_i|$ is the number of elements in set $M_i$.
I have one question: given all possible $\gamma(n)$, what is the maximum number of NC?
Empirical information:
I have been running polymer simulations in 3D with coordination number of 26 and I see that the average number of monomer-monomer contacts is approximately $2n$.
n=20,  max contacts = 109
n=32,  max contacts = 208
n=50,  max contacts = 362
n=100, max contacts = 808
n=250, max contacts = 1591

